# Windows 10 Resizes and Moves Windows when Computer Wakes

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate, resizing

When I wake my computer up my windows resize to a smaller form and they also seem to move the upper left hand corner of the screen. There is an answer to this question on [answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/windows-7-movesresizes-windows-on-monitor-power/1653aafb-848b-464a-8c69-1a68fbd106aa?page=2) but it's for Windows 7 and it's unclear what the values in the registry should be changed to. Also it's worth noting that this issue only happens when my computer is asleep for an extended amount of time which leads me to believe it's related to windows hibernation sleep mode. My computer is an Acer Aspire S7-392, I'm running it at 2560x1440 scaled at 125% Windows 10.

Comment: Do you notice that the screen resolution is different for even a split second after waking it up?

Comment: Nope, it's consistently 2560x1440 scaled

Answer (score 0):

Some display drivers seem to use the 'System scaling level' param instead of the monitor-specific scaling param when entering & leaving low-power mode (i.e. on sleep / wake).

Make sure 'Custom sizing options' (hyperlink from Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display) is set to the same as your primary screen scaling.